# Is it possible to modify or add custom http headers on a 301, 302, 303 or 307 redirect?

Tags: http, redirect, http-headers, express

Does the HTTP protocol allow a 302 request header to be modified so some parameters can be set and passed to the url receiving the request?

Answer (score 5):

302 is a response code, not a request header. The client will resolve the redirect by doing a new request for the new URL, so your client may add whatever headers it want to that new request.

A server wanting some data be sent along to the new URL should do so by appending it to the URL as querystring variables, for example: `http://example.com/new-url?variable=data`.

If the redirect is happening within your own domain you may also set a cookie which the client may send to the new address. Cookies will only be sent inside the same domain, not if you are redirecting to somewhere else.

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24296270/632951 claims that the browser is supposed to resend **an identical request** with the exact identical headers that it had sent you. And thus your first redirect to your own domain will include `Set-Cookie`, and when the browser request your 2nd url with the `Cookie` header, you again redirect him to the target web server, and the browser would then send along the repeated `Cookie` header to the target web server. What do you think?

Comment: How to detect 303 response and react to it

Comment: In my case Iam hitting api, and api is redirecting to other url (303) . Iam getting cors issue due to that, can someone help me fix that?