# How to write Authorization in response's header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to write Basic authorization in the response header and redirect it to the some url, so I do that

```
    res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic a3p0ZXN0YXBpOkthMnFUdVZN')
    res.setHeader('Location', result.data.registrationCreditUrl)
    res.writeHead(302)
    console.log(res)
    res.end('end');
```

it sends it the url and it says 401 Unauthorized, but if I do get request to that url in the postman and set header manually to (Authorization - Basic a3p0ZXN0YXBpOwqeMnFUdVZN) it works fine

Comment: I am not sure, I get the exact question here but if you want to redirect to a particular page you can use `res.redirect('yourpath')`

Comment: @sagars01, but I also want to set header, if I will not do that, the web page  I wanna redirect to, returns an error 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Yes you can do this 
`res.redirect('yourpath');
res.setHeader('Auth' , 'Token');`

or vice versa

Comment: @sagars01, No, still 401 here is my res       [Object: null prototype] {
     'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
     authorization: [ 'Authorization', 'Basic a3p04740YXBpOkthMnFUdVZN' ] } }

Comment: @Akezhan  When you do res.setHeader you are setting a response header to the client. The 302 header will tell the client to send an identical request to the url in 'location' header. Note, this will be an identical request.
Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179361/how-to-pass-data-in-http-header-while-redirecting-a-request-in-java
Also, you might want to proxy the original request instead of redirecting

Comment: you shoud set headers to the req object and not the res object. res.setHeaders() will set response headers.

Comment: @singh_arpit it does not work, on the postman I send  a request to my server with basic auth, and redirected it on my server, still 401 status code

Comment: @Akezhan I am certain that the auth header would be sent to the second server if it was sent to the first. Maybe the token itself was wrong?